# appending / removing / replacing

Tags: jquery, appendto

I'm not sure if this is the most optimal way of writing this code, but what I have *almost* works...

This is what I'm trying to do:

(1) Move the `<li></li>` element to another div when clicked

(2) Update a hidden input field by either appending or removing the `<li id>`

Note: I don't want to replace the value in the hidden input field, but add to it, so that you can wind up with a value of "u40,u56,u98" ... etc...

So, when a user clicks on an `<li>` element with the class of addable, it's removed from it's parent `<ul>` and appended to the `<ul>` in another div.  Additionally, the hidden input field will update with the id of the `<li>` element.  Conversely, if a user clicks on an `<li>` element with a class of removable, the opposite happens... The `<li>` is removed from it's parent `<ul>` and appended to the other one, and the hidden input field updates by removing the id of the `<li>` element...

This is what I have so far... It works when you add it, but the hidden input field doesn't remove the value when you click on the li.removable element.

```
$('li').click(function() {
    var uID = $(this).attr('id')+',';

    if($(this).hasClass("addable")) {

      $("input#edit-r").val($("input#edit-r").val() + uID);
      $(this).removeClass("addable");
      $(this).addClass("removable");
      $(this).appendTo($("#selections ul"));

    } else {
        var currentValue = $("input#edit-r").val();
        currentValue.replace(uID,"");
        $("input#edit-r").val(currentValue);
        $(this).removeClass("removable");
        $(this).addClass("addable");
        $(this).appendTo($(".filtered ul"));

    }
});

<div class="filtered">
    <ul>
        <li id="u40" class="addable">U40</li>
        <li id="u56" class="addable">U56</li>
        <li id="u98" class="addable">U98</li>   
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="selections">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="edit-r" value="" />
```

Comment: just a side note. Provide a jsfiddle link with your answer that people can actually test out whats happening.

Comment: You're right... I always forget about that... Sorry... But, I *did* figure it out!

Comment: Please don't write tags in question titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
currentValue.replace(uID,"");
```

To

```
currentValue = currentValue.replace(uID,"");
```

Also for optimizing your code you may use jquery objects chainability.

```
$(this).removeClass("addable").addClass("removable").appendTo("#selections ul");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to update the hidden input every time a selection is made, why not have an onsubmit handler take care of this work for you?

```
<form onsubmit="GetSelectedListIds()">
```

And:

```
function GetSelectedListIds() {
  var ids = [];
  $("li", "#selections").each(function() {
    ids[ids.length] = $(this).attr("id");
  });
  $("input#edit-r").val(ids.join());
}
```

In this manner, you don't have to worry about your hidden element staying in sync with the selected items.

Comment: I like this as well... Thank you for that